# uploading via http

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Using asp.nets upload control how do I set the code behind to save into the asp projects folder. I made a folder for userdata and a table in mysql which the link needs to be saved. Atm tho I just want to upload the data to the project folder of my choosing how is this done?

Also what are my options for the upload? I dont want to use ftp id rather use http for the upload?

path:    `~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg`

Any thing in the way of examples how to upload to the project folder via http would be great.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by the project folder you mean the root of your web application, you can use `Server.MapPath("~/")`, which will give you the physical filesystem location of the directory where your app is running. You can then append the filename you want to use to that, and write it out.

Note that you'll have to make sure that the account under which your app is running has enough permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: o damm I never thought of that, I assume it would be unwise allowing public users to upload there profile picture to the project path?

Comment: what other options do I have for uploading via http and to which directory? :S

Comment: Well, it's certainly non-standard :) Generally you'll want to upload somewhere else, but at the very least maybe to a directory _under_ your application's root. I guess it depends how you're using these files and how many of them there are.

Comment: Terrible awful idea allowing uploads to a directory under the application root. Opens up a potential arbitrary code execution scenario depending on server settings. Definitely have your upload directory completely OUTSIDE your webserver root.

Comment: @Garrith - There's really no "standard" location where ASP applications upload files, you need to figure out how to do it within the constraints of your environment. You can ask your server admins for example to create a dedicated directory somewhere with Modify permissions to the account under which your app is running, and then write everything there.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyword is "asp.net file upload". First results on Google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fileupload.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140211/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/091201-1.shtml

I think all of them may be useful for you.